# Text detection in live camera swift

Tags: swift, text-recognition, avcapturevideodataoutput

I am detecting text in live camera using swift but frames are not identified correct words.
The application works fine when I try to detect text in image and frames draw at exactly around the world.

[image: see iamge]

for live camera what i did is create a **capture video session**  and implement **AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate** then in **didOutput** i am taking buffered image and convert it in **UIImage** and detect text in it. but the same strategy is not working correctly in this case.

[image: check result in live camera]
also, **didOutput** call every time after starting video session and what I want is to only call a function when the user moves his camera or find text.

```
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            print("didOutput")
            // do stuff here
                guard let hasImage = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
                    print("no image")
                    return
                }
                let imageBuffer = hasImage
                let ciimage : CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
                liveCamImage = self.convert(cmage: ciimage)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.drawRectOnText(imagefromCam:self.liveCamImage)         
        }
    }
```

is there any solution.
//conver function

```
func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage
    {
         let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
         let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!
         let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
         return image
    }
```

Comment: Check this if helps: https://github.com/khurram18/SceneTextRecognitioniOS

Comment: show your method convert()

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your convert method:

```
func convert(samImageBuff:CIImage) -> UIImage{

let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(samImageBuff)
var ciImage: CIImage? = nil
if let imageBuffer = imageBuffer as? CVPixelBuffer {
    ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer)
}
let temporaryContext = CIContext(options: nil)
var videoImage: CGImage? = nil
if let ciImage = ciImage {
    videoImage = temporaryContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)))
}

var image: UIImage? = nil
if let videoImage = videoImage {
    image = UIImage(cgImage: videoImage)
}
CGImageRelease(videoImage)
 return image
 }
```